# How can I import my own pre-built VM images into Bluemix?

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, ibm-cloud

I have a number of my own (pre-built) VM images that I want to use on Bluemix. I can see no way of importing these images. I only seem to be able to select from the list of image templates.

Is there a way I can upload my own images or create templates from my images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned that it is possible to upload my own VM images to in creating virtual machines on Bluemix.  Since the Virtual Machines on Bluemix is running on Openstack you can bring any image that works to Openstack to Virtual Machines on Bluemix.

Use the following steps:

- In the Bluemix dashboard, go to Manage Organizations > Manage Infrastructure BETA from your organization view.
- Click Upload Image from the public cloud.
- Enter the URL where the image is located. This **MUST** be a public URL that Bluemix can access to upload the image from.
- Click UPLOAD.

Additionally, you can access Horizon and Keystone as well.  To do this click on the Virtual Machines and click "Show Credentials"